# Can Freestyle draw lines between intersecting meshes like SoftImage?

Tags: freestyle

[image]

I used a translator. 
Please understand if I wrote the wrong sentence

I think the last question is difficult to understand.
So I Attached was a picture.

The problem of the picture 1 and 2.
I want to resolve, as the third picture.

And fourth and fifth picture is a way to resolve in a soft image.
So I want to know that possible a blender  tool solve same problem.

I'm sorry to bother you. But I'm really need your help.

---

​I used translator.

Photo 1 problem occurred twice.

I want to solve as picture 3

The Softimage picture is 4 to 5 times.

4 Blender 5 times as possible too.

The request help.

​

---

Comment: No, Freestyle in Blender does not support intersecting geometry.